# Should I install a fast fan at the rear of the computer case?

Tags: fan, cooling

Just discover that my fan at the rear became very slow speed. Thinking of buying a new one.

When I arrived the store, there are many different fans of different speed.

For example, 8000rpm, I can merely feel some slow air movement next to it.
10000rpm, it started to have some wind.
15000rpm, the wind is quite fast and I am contented with its speed.
20000rpm, it is really fast. You can dry your hair with it.

But do I need such a fast fan? To clarify it, what is the setup which may create so much heat which I need a very fast fan to blow them off? Is 8000rpm enough?

Comment: 20000rpm fans can get quite noisy... just fyi.

Comment: There is no way you have an 8,000 to 20,000 RPM fan in your case.  I think you added an extra 0 everywhere, lol.

Comment: I second KronoS, watch for noise, you don't want it to sound like its about to take off.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on a lot of things.
In most cases a fan that can dry your hair won't be needed.

Take into account these questions.

Is your case crammed?

Are your components top of the line?

Do you have overclocked components?

Have you had overheating issues before?

You will want to take into account all of your answers to these questions. A good place to start before deciding on what type of fan you need is to download a temp monitor.

Speedfan is a good one which allows you to reduce and increase fan speed as well as monitor temperature.

Who knows you may already be at a decent temp.

[Speedfan Download](http://www.almico.com/sfdownload.php)

Comment: [direction of the fans](http://superuser.com/questions/61441/optimal-fan-placement-and-direction-for-air-cooling-a-computer) is also an important thing to consider as well

Answer (score 0):

You don't state your OS. Use some software that lets you monitor CPU (and maybe GPU) temperatures. If they're in range now, you don't need a faster fan.