# CPU overheating when stresstesting GPU! (laptop)

Tags: cpu, gpu, cooling, overheating, laptop-repair

So, one day I had no problems (playing GTA V), and then the next day my CPU overheats really badly up to 93°C (Tested with Speccy and CoreTemp) and this keeps happening, I used to play GTA V with max settings no problems, and now im on the lowest settings with massive lagg. So I went to stresstest my laptop with AIDA64 Extreme, first I did my CPU, which went up to about 75°C average with 82°C max, next I went and stresstested just my GPU, and then all my CPU temperatures go up to like 90 - 95°C within seconds, is this normal? if not, does anyone know whats wrong?

Laptop: Acer Aspire 7: A715-72G-56BC

BTW, on overage it takes around 2-3 minutes (when playing GTA V) to get up to these temperatures. And also I don't overclock. I know this question has been asked before, but that didn't really get answered and certainly didn't help me.

Comment: Check your CPU fan and thermal grease.

Comment: Related [Troubleshooting an overheating CPU - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/389573/troubleshooting-an-overheating-cpu?rq=1)

Comment: @DavidPostill I think the thermal grease might be the problem, should I replace this myself or should i leave this to a professional?